# I want to open external installed applications when clicking on share icon by jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

This is the dropdown menu which opens when we click on share icon, but I want to open external apps installed in mobile by jQuery Mobile.

[image: Image1]

I want to open external social apps like this in android by jQuery Mobile

[image: Image2]